# PHP validation help. First and last name, validated as required fields

Tags: php

This link leads to where my code is ran.

http://erobi022.pairserver.com/phpvalidate1.php

```
<!DOC TYPE html>
<html>
<body>
This is a simple form
<form method="post" action="send_phpvalidate1.php">

Please enter your first name: <input type="text" name="First"></p>

Please enter your last name: <input type="text" name="Last"></p>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Once the submit button is hit, all data is sent and posted here. I can get first and last name to output fine, but if i leave them blank it will only say that i left my first name field blank.

http://erobi022.pairserver.com/send_phpvalidate1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Welcome, 
</P>
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $name1 = $_POST["First"];
    if (empty($name1)) {
        echo "You've entered nothing for first name";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href='phpvalidate1.php?text=hello>Click here to fix</a>";
        die; //if you mess up, youll have to fix it
    } else {
        echo " Your first name is $name1 ";
    }
}

echo "<br>";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $name2 = $_POST["Last"];
    if (empty($name2)) {
        echo "You've entered nothing for last name";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href='phpvalidate1.php?text=hello>Click here to fix</a>";
        die; //if you mess up, youll have to fix it
        } else {
         echo " Your last name is $name2 ";
    }
}

?>


<?php // can have multiple php sections

echo "<a href='phpvalidate1.php'>Return to form</a></p>";
//have to use a simple qoute within html to make it work


?> </p>

<a href=".">Return to home page</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you used  two if condition?

Comment: Use if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  //check here for both texbox }

Comment: because you have `die; //if you mess up, youll have to fix it` in there, which stops further processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use that using HTML 5, simple

```
<!DOC TYPE html>
<html>
<body>
This is a simple form
<form method="post" action="send_phpvalidate1.php">

Please enter your first name: <input  required="required"  type="text" name="First"></p>

Please enter your last name: <input  required="required"  type="text" name="Last"></p>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use two big `if`s, just replace your PHP code with this :

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name1 = $_POST["First"];
    $name2 = $_POST["Last"];
    if (empty($name1) || empty($name2)) {
        echo "Please complete both the fields.";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a href='phpvalidate1.php?text=hello>Click here to fix</a>";
        die; //if you mess up, youll have to fix it
    } else {
        echo " Your name is $name1 $name2";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you! this was very helpful! But one last question, condensing my code to this doesnt give me the option of the "Click here to fix" link, it just says , "Please complete both fields".

Answer (score 0):

First, whenever there is a die() statement,only the codes that appear before that run, the ones which come after don't get to run(in relation to your code.)

you can also trim your codes down this way and it will still work

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$name1 = $_POST["First"];
$name2 = $_POST["Last"];
if (empty($name1) || empty($name2)) {
    echo "Please complete both the fields.";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='phpvalidate1.php?text=hello>Click here to fix</a>";
    die; //if you mess up, youll have to fix it
} else {
    echo " Your name is $name1 $name2";
 }
}
?>
```